# How to Automatically copy keyframe from one object to other with one step

Tags: python, animation

I am struggling about a week figuring out how to do this.
For example i have 5 objects, for the object1 I put visibility on 1 frame and invisible on 2 frame.
then i need all other objects to have the same keyframes but with the 1 framestep from previous
1-frame we see object 1, 2-frame we see object 2 and further.

Comment: you can do this in the graph editor ...but this is also manually. There is AFAIK no automatic thing for this. Or you do it with python. Some add-ons maybe could do that.

Comment: This isn't a response to your question but you can do this by adding a mask modifier on the object and adding a driver to the visibility of the modifier with an expression set to `frame != 1` to hide the object on all frames but the first one. Tell me if that would do I'll post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is a python solution:

result looks like this: https://youtu.be/HsVNCyuWyDY

what you have to do:

Create a collection with the name "Automatic_frame_visibility" and put all your objects in there.
After running the script and starting your animation, each object will be visible in the order of the collection with one frame visibility.

[image]

python script:

```
import bpy


def frame_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    counter = 0
 
    for eachObject in list:
        if scene.frame_current - 1 == counter:
            eachObject.hide_render = False
            eachObject.hide_viewport = False
        else:
            eachObject.hide_render = True
            eachObject.hide_viewport = True  
        counter += 1
        
print ("-------- Script started")

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler)


list = []

for eachObject in bpy.data.collections['Automatic_frame_visibility'].objects:
   list.append(eachObject)
```

Comment: moonboots will come with a much more elegant solution, and Robin will solve this procedurally. And of course - batFinger will have a perfect python solution for all cases - mine just works for your case - and nothing else.