# switch objects in the same position

Tags: objects, visibility

I'd like to render a table with different objects on it, one by one. The table with a book, then with a cup of coffee, and so on...

My current solution is to have all objects visible but out of camera view, and I create keyframes for each object positioned in view on the table. Then I render the whole animation as individual images and it works well, but is very inefficient.

Is it possible to have all of those objects in a collection and animate it so each frame automatically shows a different object, through linking to an empty as placeholder on the table, a modifier or another method (except scripting)?

Follow up question: Can something similar be done to apply different textures to the table?

Any help, even just a nudge in the right direction, will be appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Automatically copy keyframe from one object to other with one step](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220894/how-to-automatically-copy-keyframe-from-one-object-to-other-with-one-step)

Comment: it is AFAIK not possible without scripting

Comment: maybe...with an add-on

Comment: Well,yes. The easy way is to Move different objects in different collection amd then keyframe collection visibility easily. If you don't want that,just enable visible in render and keyframe that.

Comment: And the easy way to swap up the textures is to put all textures into one material and then use mix shader node to just enable one out of the two. Keyframe it and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks @Rajjaiswal, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you a free addon which I created, specifically for this situation:

**Object Sequence** (https://github.com/sacrish/Object-Sequence)

After installing the addon, first set up your scene with an hierarchy like this:

[image: scene hierarchy]

Basically put the objects which need to be switched in a separate collection (here I named it "objects"), meanwhile keep all other things like the table, camera, etc. in another collection.

Open **Object Sequence** panel from the "Misc" tab, select your collection of objects, and hit **Sequentialize**.

[image: Object Sequence panel]

And you will notice in the timeline that the visibilities of the objects have been keyframed, with their object names labeled on corresponding frames.

[image: timeline]

Now hit **Render Sequence** in the Object Sequence panel, and the frames will be automatically rendered and saved. Save location is set in your Output panel, so make sure it's correct before hitting render.

I also have a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQukkiExx-s) which demonstrates the workflow.

Comment: Thank you @sacrish, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @TheBelgianNomad You're welcome. Glad it helps :)